# How to load RSA key in PEM format using Openssl 3.0

Tags: c, openssl

Sorry for my poor English and I only know a little about openssl.
I was asked to update my Openssl version from 1.1.1q to 3.0.7. And at load key part, The previous function is deprecated, so I don't know how to load RSA Key from PEM file.

The previous function I use:

```
RSA *g_RSA = NULL;

g_RSA = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
g_RSA = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(bp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The function I tryed, but when I want to get the param like "n","e","d", the application occurred an interruption.

```
EVP_PKEY* g_RSA = NULL;
g_RSA = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param(g_RSA, "n", &n);
    EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param(g_RSA, "e", &e);
    EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param(g_RSA, "d", &d);
```

I also found a sample from Openssl web, but the sample didn't include how can I creat the key from decoded data.
[image]

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The picture didn't show well, the code I saw in Openssl Web is "OSSL_DECODER_from_bio(dctx, bio)", but it did't give a sample about how to create key from the decoded data.

Comment: I already tried "g_RSA = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY_ex(bp, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);", but the value returned is NULL.